# How to change buttons layout from horizontal to vertical?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, vertical-alignment

I'm translating a chinese app and I want to change the bottom buttons layout from horizontal to vertical in order to fit correctly the translations. I've been playing with the orientation and gravity from the LinearLayout and CheckedTextView but the buttons stay always in horizontal.

This is the xml code,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@drawable/homepage_ground"     android:layout_width="fill_parent"     android:layout_height="fill_parent"     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:nav_stick="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<include layout="@layout/title_bar_transparent_white" />
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="0.0px" android:layout_weight="1.0">
    <com.rockrobo.ui.RRNavigateStick android:id="@id/navigate_stick" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
    <TextView android:id="@id/rc_starting" android:visibility="gone" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginTop="10.0dip" android:text="@string/rc_starting_up" android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
<LinearLayout android:layout_gravity="center" android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/rc_bot_margin">
    <CheckedTextView android:textColor="@color/rc_button_text_color" android:gravity="center" android:id="@id/spot_clean" android:background="@drawable/rc_button_bg" android:clickable="true" android:layout_width="@dimen/rc_button_width" android:layout_height="@dimen/rc_button_height" android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/rc_bot_bar_gap" android:text="@string/rr_spot" />
    <CheckedTextView android:textColor="@color/rc_button_text_color" android:gravity="center" android:id="@id/clean" android:background="@drawable/rc_button_bg" android:clickable="true" android:layout_width="@dimen/rc_button_width" android:layout_height="@dimen/rc_button_height" android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/rc_bot_bar_gap" android:text="@string/rr_clean" />
    <CheckedTextView android:textColor="@color/rc_button_text_color" android:gravity="center" android:id="@id/charge" android:background="@drawable/rc_button_bg" android:clickable="true" android:layout_width="@dimen/rc_button_width" android:layout_height="@dimen/rc_button_height" android:text="@string/rr_charge" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Could anybody help? Thanks.

Comment: Can you attach screenshot

Answer (score 0):

Hi try changing linear layout width to match parent and orientation to vertical

Comment: Please try writing such answer as a comment.